# why does System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer deserialize string elements with the attribute xsi:nil="true", as the empty string instead of null?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I am deserializing the follwing XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <x xsi:nil="true" />
    <y xsi:nil="true" />
    <z xsi:nil="true" />
</root>
```

As the following class, using XmlSerializer.Deserialize():

```
public class root
{
    public string x { get; set; } // is deserialized as ""
    public string? y { get; set; } // is deserialized as ""
    public int? z { get; set; }
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string? b { get; set; }

}
```

The result is that the string values `x` and `y` are serialized as the empty string `""`. But i expect them to be deserialized as `null`, like the int value `z`. I assume that `xsi:nil="true"` is equivalent to `null`, so this seems wrong.

**Questions**

- Is this behavior documented somewhere? (I can't find it)
- Is this specific to .NET?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlElementAttribute_IsNullable  ... it is specific to `XmlSerializer` ... if you would use XmlDocument like `var doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.LoadXml(xml);
 doc.SelectNodes("root").Cast<XmlElement>().First().Value.Dump();` it would return null

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/y2OUdY

Comment: It is using the namespace xsi.  You can add above the properties the following : [XmlElement(Namespace = string.Empty)]

Comment: @Selvin thanks. but, `doc.SelectNodes("root").Cast<XmlElement>().First().Value` is also `null`, when the first element has a value, like `<x>hello</x>`. i did see that documentation about the attribute, but i was hoping for an explanation of the default behavior. having to use the redundant attribute `[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]` increases the chance of making a mistake, as i have a lot of classes and will be making many more in the future

Comment: my bad ... it was value of root ... it should be [`doc.SelectNodes("root/x").Cast<XmlElement>().First().FirstChild?.Value`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y2OUdY)